# How to work with an aggregate value set for multiple items

Tags: mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics, disaggregation

I have a natural disasters dataset from [EMDAT](https://public.emdat.be) that records the impact of a disaster as an aggregate (Total) against locations as follows:

| Total affected | Locations |
| --- | --- |
| 10000 | locationA locationB locationC |

I need to assign each location its own total affected value.

### What I have tried

I have divided the total value by the number of locations in the given row. That is.

| Total affected | Locations |
| --- | --- |
| 3333 | locationA |
| 3333 | locationB |
| 3334 | locationC |

Is there a better method I can use to disaggregate the value for the locations given?

### EDIT

The value provided in the dataset is an aggregated value for more than one location. There is no information on the exact value for each location recorded in the same row. Currently, I am dividing the given aggregated value by the number of locations recorded against this aggregate value.

For example;
if the total affected value is 10 and the no. locations recorded in that row is 5, I collapse the dataset so that each of the locations has a value of two.

Is there a better way to disaggregate apart from the above approach?

Comment: Do you have any additional information, about how much should go to each location?

Comment: Could you please add some more information about the EMDAT dataset you are using and what you are trying to achieve. As it's currently written, there is not enough detail to provide an answer.

Comment: @Lynn please see the edit on the post.

Comment: Does "Total affected" refer to number of people or households affected by the disaster? You would have to make assumptions, and one assumption could be to divide it proportional to populaton size, if you can obtain estimates of the number of people living in each location.

Comment: @dipetkov that is a very interesting approach. Total affected here is the number of people affected by the disaster. You are proposing that I also get the total population across these locations, then find the percentage of each location’s contribution to this total population number. Use these percentages to disaggregate the total affected for the respective locations. Do I have a precise grasp of your proposed approach?

Comment: Yes, precisely. Say you know that *x* people live in A, *y* people live in B, *z* people live in C (perhaps from a census that's taken around the time of the disaster). Then split 10k into *10k * x/(x+y+z)*, *10k * y/(x+y+z)* and *10k * z/(x+y+z)*. Obviously, you make the assumption that locations A, B and C are similarly affected.

Comment: Thank you @dipetkov let me try this and see how different the result will be.

Comment: @dipetkov I used the approach you proposed, and this is what I have found;
1. It is only suitable for the visualization of the dataset
2. When it comes to risk analysis for the different locations, we do not get an accurate picture of the risk.
I think this problem would best be addressed by those who collect the data.

Comment: @JobCollins Thanks for the update. Good visualizations help but are not the end goal. In your case it seems the data (as it is currently) doesn't contain enough information/signal.